# Can You Create a Map that is 1:1 Scale with the United States in UE4 & UE5

Tags: unreal-4, open-world, unreal-5

Is it theoretically possible to create a Fortnite graphic quality map in UE4 or UE5 that is 1:1 scale with the United States and be able to have 330 million people all online in that map at once playing Fortnite all in real-time with no performance issues whatsoever?  If not, how big of a world can you create with the Engine?

Comment: When a question is closed on this site, it is not appropriate to slightly rephrase it and ask it again as a new post. You should instead edit your existing question into something that is on-topic and within an answerable scope. Once it's been reshaped into a form suitable for our Q&A format, it can be re-opened for answers.

Comment: Are you the one who closed it?  I don't know how to ask the question any more focused than this?  I think you're being pedantic.  Can you help with a suggestion?  I'm simply trying to ask the community a question about load size for an online game.

Comment: What about the 2nd question?  I tried to be more specific with an example.  Can you release that one so others can share comments?

Comment: You should go back and re-read DMGregory's comments on the other question. Your second question is based on invalid assumptions. There *isn't* a limit to how big of a world you can create.

Comment: As I've explained to you in a previous comment, there is no simple map size number that anyone can give you. Your question is based on an incorrect assumption about how games are made - ie. that we put all our content in one big map as big as the engine allows. That approach just does not scale to enormous open world games of the scale you're describing. Instead, games load just a small piece of the map around the local player, and fake the distant parts in various clever ways. The limitation is how much content your team can build and how cleverly you fake things, not the engine's size bound.

Comment: And towards the "330 million people all online" aspect, that many people all connecting to one online system is unprecedented outside of the world's largest sites like YouTube and Facebook. You will have to overcome the same kinds of issues that they have plus many new ones involved in the "game" part of your idea. That is going to be a massive technical challenge.

Comment: Lastly, if you wanted to improve your question and make it more "focused" you need to define a bunch of requirements. How many people online? What are they doing in the  online world? How do they interact with each other? What do you want to happen when 1000 people all go to the same spot in the world and try to interact? (And so many more questions like this that need to be answered to "focus" your question.)